# how to use a forloop for my blog post to stand next to each other in django

Tags: jquery, css, django, python-3.x

actually my title might not be clear but let me explain,i have list of blogpost i want to use forloop to make each post stand next to each other,instead they all stood straight which i dont want here is the post [this is how it is in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ole9D.jpg) , {[this is how i want them to look like in a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/969Ag.jpg)}

### blog.html

```
 <section class="ftco-section bg-light" id="blog-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-10 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
            <h2 class="mb-4">Gets Every Single Updates Here</h2>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5 pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">
           {% for blog in blog_post %}
            <div class="blog-entry ">  
              <a href="blog-single.html" class="block-20" style="background-image: url({{ blog.thumbnail.url }})">
              </a>
              <div class="text d-block">
                <div class="meta mb-3">
                  <div><a href="#">{{ blog.timestamp|timesince }} ago</a></div>
                  <div><a href="#">{{ blog.user }}</a></div>
                  <div><a href="#" class="meta-chat"><span class="icon-eye"></span>{{ blog.view_count }}</a></div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="heading"><a href="#">{{ blog.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</p>
                <p><a href="blog-single.html" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>
            
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You need to move the for loop to the parent div so it will go like this: ".....  {% for blog in blog_post %} <div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">..." I'm not sure if there are other problems.

Comment: omg thanks i really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div class="row d-flex">
         {% for blog in blog_post %}
          <div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate">
            <div class="blog-entry "> 
              <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="block-20" style="background-image: url({{ blog.image.url }})"></a>
              <div class="text d-block">
                <div class="meta mb-3">
                  <div>{{ blog.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                  <div><a href="{% url 'user-blog' blog.doctor.user.username %}">Written By {{ blog.doctor.user.username }}</a></div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="heading"><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}">{{ blog.title }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ blog.summary }} </p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'blog-detail' blog.id %}" class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          
          {% endfor %}
        </div> 
      </div>
```